# What is wrong with this lines of my R script?What I am missing?

Tags: r

Ok, So I got this long line of code as a part of a script which someone wrote ( I know it seems horrible). So I tried to simplify it.

```
dH=((-HMF )*( 1.013*10^10*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((292131/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((331573/1.987)*(1/284.9-1/(T+273.2))))))*( 4.371*10^-8*((RH+273.2)/298)*exp((55763.5/1.987)*(1/298-1/(RH+273.2)))/(1+(exp((77245.3/1.987)*(1/365.3-1/(RH+273.2))))))*(H[hour]*I[hour]))-((LGR1)*( 123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2)))))) *H[hour]*L1a[hour])-((LGR2)*( 123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2)))))) *H[hour]*L2a[hour])- ((LGR3)*( 123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2)))))) *H[hour]*L3a[hour])
```

I simplified it like this:

```
a<-(1.013*10^10*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((292131/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((331573/1.987)*(1/284.9-1/(T+273.2))))))

b<-( 4.371*10^-8*((RH+273.2)/298)*exp((55763.5/1.987)*(1/298-1/(RH+273.2)))/(1+(exp((77245.3/1.987)*(1/365.3-1/(RH+273.2))))))

c<-(123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2))))))

d<-(1.7168*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((14275.4/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((49087.1/1.987)*(1/298.85-1/(T+273.2))))))

dH=((-HMF )*a*b*(H[hour]*I[hour]))-(LGR1*c*H[hour]*L1a[hour])-(LGR2*c*H[hour]*L2a[hour])-(LGR3*c*H[hour]*L3a[hour])
```

So what basically the model does is that it takes T and RH for different hours and LGR1,LGR2 and LGR3 are constant values. Also L1a, L2a and L3a are also claculated for different hours and a,b,c and d are used to calculate L1a, L2a and L3a for different hours. 
The odd thing is that when I only and simply replace the messy long formula with a,b,c, and d my output model changes which I expect not to. I know it might be vague but I was not sure if I can post the full script here.

Thanks in advance for your advice

Comment: You probably missed some parenthesis order, minus signs or something like that. I'd suggest that you erase a, b and c and do it all again, trying to find the mistake is probably even harder.

Comment: You have `1.7168` in `d` where in the original expression you have `123.8`.

Comment: I checked it many many times, I simply copied those long formula and assigned them a,b,c and d. I think if the issue is parenthesis  or minus sign then it will give me error message, but it goes all file. The thing is that output changes ( with simplified verion the output makes sense though!)

Comment: Which part @jbaums? the 'd' is '1.7168' and 'c' is '123.8' . I only have 'd'.

Comment: I think I misread... I figured you provided `d` because it was actually used, but on second glance it's not used at all.

Comment: Using fake data, I get exactly the same values.

Comment: Yep, with these data there is no difference between the two expressions: `T <- runif(1); H <- runif(1); hour <- 1; RH <- runif(1); HMF <- runif(1); I <- runif(1); LGR1 <- runif(1); L1a <- runif(1); LGR2 <- runif(1); L2a <- runif(1); LGR3 <- runif(1); L3a <- runif(1)`

Answer (score 0):

I took it into an editor that is syntax-aware and use the parenthesis matching capacity to break into its 4 arithmetic terms (separated by minus signs):

```
dH=
((-HMF )*( 1.013*10^10*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((292131/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((331573/1.987)*(1/284.9-1/(T+273.2))))))*( 4.371*10^-8*((RH+273.2)/298)*exp((55763.5/1.987)*(1/298-1/(RH+273.2)))/(1+(exp((77245.3/1.987)*(1/365.3-1/(RH+273.2))))))*(H[hour]*I[hour]))-

((LGR1)*( 123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2)))))) *H[hour]*L1a[hour])-

((LGR2)*( 123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2)))))) *H[hour]*L2a[hour])- 

((LGR3)*( 123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2)))))) *H[hour]*L3a[hour])
```

The fact that your terms seem to start in different sections of that expression make me think you separated terms inappropriately. It does appear (in my editor that the last three terms all share a common factor and tht the only items that vary in those three terms are the first and last factors:

```
( 123.8*((T+273.2)/298)*exp((-390540/1.987)*(1/298-1/(T+273.2)))/(1+(exp((-402880/1.987)*(1/300.1-1/(T+273.2)))))) *H[hour]
```